# where are my Marvell ethernet controller's Windows device driver's messages logged?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have a motherboard (GA-965P-DS3) with an onboard Marvell Yukon 88E8056 ethernet controller. I was looking at the "advanced" tab of the windows device driver recently and noticed there is an attribute in this section with the title `Log Status Messages`. The possible values for this attribute are
`All Messages`, `Errors`, `None`, `Status Messages`, and `Warnings`.

I was wondering how I would view any messages that my ethernet controller's device driver might log.

Beyond this, I was also wondering what properties the various attributes in this section affect. Maybe there is an article or BLOG entry that provides more insight about what they do?

I am using Windows 7 Home Premium, 64-bit.

Comment: i have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Marvell's installation files on your system, there's a useful README detailing the driver's options. In it, it states that the logs are in Windows' event viewer. My particular logs come up as [Source: yukonw7]

1. Navigate to C:/Program Files/Marvell/Miniport Driver/README.htm

You'll find this or a similar message:

> Log Status Messages Specifies the messages which are to be logged in
>   the event log.
>
> Default value: "Status Messages" Valid values:
>
> ```
> "All Messages" - Should only be used for test purposes.
> "Status Messages" - The driver will generate an event log entry every time the link status changes.
> "Warnings" - Only warning or error messages will be generated.
> "Errors" - Only error messages will be generated.
> "None" - All driver messages will be suppressed (not recommended).
> ```

If you do not have this readme, Intel may still have it on its servers:

http://downloadmirror.intel.com/9578/eng/yk51x64.txt

To access the event viewer, go to Start and type in the search box "event viewer." Click on either "Event Viewer" or "view event logs." With Event Viewer open, navigate to Windows Logs|System yukonw7 or some variation should be there, if you have any logs. If not, go back into your ethernet settings and make a change or two in the settings. That should invoke a log or two. If all fails, set the log settings to log "All Messages."

Comment: Thanks. I'd pretty much given up on this question. But you info was very complete and took me right where I needed to go to review the logs.